# Join a dataframe with date+timestamp index and dataframe with date index

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to join to a dataframe `df` with an index `datetime64[ns]` format such as `'2014-09-26 15:15:00'` and another dataframe but with index `datetime64[ns]` format such as `'2014-09-26` but with no timestamp?

For example:

```
print df1
                           Vol 
    2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.333315 
    2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.228341
    2011-01-05 10:00:00  0.207289
```

and df2

```
            macro_ind
2010-01-05  0.216485  
2010-01-06  0.201550
2010-01-07  0.187641 
2010-01-08  0.176686
```

I tried using `df1.join(df2)` and was hoping to get:

```
                     Vol     macro_ind
2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.333315 0.216485  
2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.228341 0.216485  
2011-01-05 10:00:00  0.207289 0.216485
```

but no success... I could use `pd.merge` but that forces me to create a date column and reset my index and so on... a lot of steps that I wish to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `macro_ind` are also dated `2011`. I would recommend setting the respective `time` columns as ordinary columns like so:

```
date:

        date  macro_ind
0 2011-01-05   0.216485
1 2011-01-06   0.201550
2 2011-01-07   0.187641
3 2011-01-08   0.176686

time: 
                 time       Vol
0 2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.333315
1 2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.228341
2 2011-01-05 10:00:00  0.207289
```

Then, the following works:

```
time_df['date'] = time_df.time.apply(lambda x: x.date())
date_df['date'] = date_df.date.apply(lambda x: x.date())
time_df = time_df.merge(date_df, how='left', on='date').drop('date', axis=1)

                 time       Vol  macro_ind
0 2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.333315   0.216485
1 2011-01-05 09:45:00  0.228341   0.216485
2 2011-01-05 10:00:00  0.207289   0.216485
```

Comment: Yes I was using something similar before. There's nothing with `join`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not aware of a way to temporarily convert a `DateTimeIndex` to `date`. Maybe someone else knows.